# Why doesn't the linear shortest path algorithm work for non-directed cyclic graphs?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, shortest-path, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have the basic linear shortest path algorithm implemented in Python. According to various sites I've come across, this only works for directed acyclic graphs, including [this](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2012/10/28/computer-algorithms-shortest-path-in-a-directed-acyclic-graph/), [this](http://allaboutalgorithms.wordpress.com/2011/11/02/shortest-path-in-directed-acyclic-graphs/), and [this](http://youtu.be/2E7MmKv0Y24?t=18m). However, I don't see why this is the case.

I've even tested the algorithm against graphs with cycles and un-directed edges, and it worked fine.

So the question is, **why doesn't the linear shortest path algorithm work for non-directed cyclic graphs?** Side question, **what is the name of this algorithm?**

For reference, here is the code I wrote for the algorithm:

```
def shortestPath(start, end, graph):
    # First, topologically sort the graph, to determine which order to traverse it in
    sorted = toplogicalSort(start, graph)

    # Get ready to store the current weight of each node's path, and their predecessor
    weights = [0] + [float('inf')] * (len(graph) - 1)
    predecessor = [0] * len(graph)

    # Next, relaxes all edges in the order of sorted nodes
    for node in sorted:
        for neighbour in graph[node]:

            # Checks if it would be cheaper to take this path, as opposed to the last path
            if weights[neighbour[0]] > weights[node] + neighbour[1]:

                # If it is, then adjust the weight and predecessor
                weights[neighbour[0]] = weights[node] + neighbour[1]
                predecessor[neighbour[0]] = node

    # Returns the shortest path to the end
    path = [end]
    while path[len(path) - 1] != start:
        path.append(predecessor[path[len(path) - 1]])
    return path[::-1]
```

**Edit:** As asked by Beta, here is the topological sort:

```
# Toplogically sorts the graph given, starting from the start point given.
def toplogicalSort(start, graph):
    # Runs a DFS on all nodes connected to the starting node in the graph
    def DFS(start):
        for node in graph[start]:
            if not node[0] in checked:
                checked[node[0]] = True
                DFS(node[0])
        finish.append(start)

    # Stores the finish point of all nodes in the graph, and a boolean stating if they have been checked
    finish, checked = [], {}
    DFS(start)

    # Reverses the order of the sort, to get a proper topology; then returns
    return finish[::-1]
```

Comment: The algorithm in your first reference involves a topological sorting of the graph. How do you do that with a graph that contains a cycle?

Comment: Added the method to the question

Comment: It's not "how do you implement that". The question is, what do you think topologically sorting a cyclic graph would even mean?

Comment: If it's not an acyclic graph, the order your DFS creates on the graph depends on the way it's represented in addition to the topology of the graph. What I mean is: if you take the same cyclic graph and store it in memory in two different structures (for example, as adjacency lists with different orders), the DFS may give you different results with regard to the topological order. Since the shortest path processing afterwards relies on that order, your results will not be correct in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you cannot topologically sort a graph with cycles (therefore undirected graphs are also out of the question as you can't tell which node should come before another).

Edit: After reading the comments, I think that's actually what @Beta meant.

Answer (score 0):

When there is cycle, topological sort cannot guarantee the correct ordering of the shortest path.

For example, we have a graph:

```
A->C, A->B, B->C, C->B, B->D
```

Say the correct shortest path is:

```
A->C->B->D
```

But topological sort can generate an order:

```
A->B->C->D
```

Although it will update `B` to the correct order when visiting `C`, but `B` won't be visited again, thus not able to propagate correct weight to `D`. (Path happens to be correct though.)